# HikariCP Maximum Pool Size with SSDs

Tags: connection-pooling, hikaricp

I've implemented HikariCP for a few apps. So far, in the "simpliest" one it's working pretty good, even boosting performance and showing where we should try to optimize.

Anyway, that app is in a server with 4 HDD on RAID and it's an 8-core machine. We also have another app that will be hosted in the cloud, with SSD storage.

I know the [formula](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/About-Pool-Sizing#connections--core_count--2--effective_spindle_count) given by the PostgreSQL team addresses the maximum size pool, but according to Hikari's documentation, [the behaviour with SSDs hasn't been analized yet](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/About-Pool-Sizing). That 'yet' made me go and look for an answer, but since my Googling hasn't been much effective (I might be using wrong keywords) I come here.

**Does anyone know how the formula scales with SSD?** A quick guess is that if I can't actually take `effective_spindle_count` into consideration given how different SSDs and HDDs are, then I could scale the number based of read/write speed or something, but I doubt is that simple.

Good day!

Answer (score 0):

From the same [link I quoted back when I asked the question](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/About-Pool-Sizing), which was a quote from the article, new information was added about SSDs with pooling.

tl;dr is "Since there is less/no seek time, fewer connections in the pool would be better", with them giving an example that a single connection per CPU core would be ideal because of less overhead as it's not changing contexts. They do not provide a definitive answer, as "*More threads only perform better when blocking creates opportunities for executing.*", which I think is fair.

At that point, I'm leaning to believe that a pool size equal to the number of cores in the system is ideal, because of the low to no overhead while having, at the same time, *probably* more threads than needed *in case* any blocking operation kicks in.

I lack the expertise to give a definitive and well-backed-up answer (I'm absolutely ok with being proven wrong, as long as we can have an answer), but from what I've read and understood, I think is safe to say that:

If the application's data sources read from an HDD: Stick to the formula.

> (max) connections = ((core_count * 2) + effective_spindle_count)

If the application's data sources read from an SSD: The pool size should be equal to the core count of the machine where the application is running.

> (max) connections = core_count

Of course, and quoting the article once more: **Pool sizing is ultimately very specific to deployments.**